# How to programmatically retrieve text in RTL format

Tags: javascript, css, right-to-left

I have the following text:

`ךלחיעכגדש(does this work)ךלחיעכגדשךלחיעכגדשךלחיעכגדש`

It is displayed in a div with `direction: rtl` applied to it, which causes it to display like this:

`ךלחיעכגדשךלחיעכגדשךלחיעכגדש(does this work)ךלחיעכגדש`

When I try to copy text that is in inside the div into the clipboard, the `direction: rtl` style is not preserved, and the original format of the string is copied over, causing the text to display like this when I paste:

`ךלחיעכגדש(does this work)ךלחיעכגדשךלחיעכגדשךלחיעכגדש`

What can I do to preserve `direction: rtl` formatting on copy / paste event? Is there any JavaScript function / library that I can utilize in a copy event to programmatically do what `direction: rtl` is doing?

```html
<div style="direction:rtl">
   ךלחיעכגדש(does this work)ךלחיעכגדשךלחיעכגדשךלחיעכגדש
</div>
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1tbc2xpq/)

If you run the jsfiddle and copy the text, you will notice that styling is not preserved and the original string is displayed.

Thank you!

Comment: its a display property, not a property of the string itself.

Comment: I am not sure what you expect, but try to add an RLE character `&#x202b;` in the beginning of the text. It won't change the display of the `div` with `direction:rtl`, but can improve the way this text behaves in clipboard.